# Почему может формироваться некорректный XML для веб сервиса

Tags: c#, xml, веб-служба

У меня есть приложение, которое общается с веб сервисом. Выглядит это примерно так:

```cs
WebRemoteService.Service client = WebRemoteService.Service ();
//...
var result = client.MyMethod (strValue1, strValue2, arrDoubleValue3, arrDoubleValue4, strValue5, arrStrValue6, myEnumValue7 );
```

У меня это отлично работает, но вот у одного из пользователей приложения возникает ошибка: `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Серверу не удалось прочитать запрос. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: В документе XML (1, 49258) присутствует ошибка.`

Причём ошибка проявляется лишь один раз при первом запуске приложения или смене значения myEnumValue7. Сам Enum я уже проверил, он в порядке (там всего 3 значения). Пришёл в приложение по веб ссылке на сервис. Её я на всякий случай обновил, но ничего нового не пришло. Да и если бы дело было только в этом, то наверняка ситуация была бы стабильной, а не воспроизводилась лишь один раз.
Ещё могу уточнить, что для myEnumValue7 приемлемо значение null. Тип данных со знаком вопроса, а в веб сервисе в методе для данного параметра используется Nulllable<*тип данных моего Enum*> *Параметр*. Хотя, на сколько я знаю, это вот совсем не должно мешать.

У меня ситуация не воспроизводится. Я пробовал с помощью утилиты Fiddler смотреть что за XML у меня отправляется при запросе, но он выглядит вполне обыкновенным. Разве что длинным из-за размера массивов, но он длинный всегда, а не только при первом запуске.
Никакого способа залогировать отправляемый XML файл не вижу (скажите, если он всё же есть). К сожалению, поставить Fiddler на компьютер пользователя и посмотреть что отправляется - не вариант.

Подскажите, куда ещё копать?

Comment: то есть, ручками xml не парсится, и пакеты по сети тоже ручками не отсылаются не принимаются? все делается встроенными средствами языка/дотнета?

Comment: Я не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду... Есть веб сервис в котором есть публичный метод MyMethod. Есть моё приложение, которое вызывает этот метод с помощью client.MyMethod (...). При попытке вызова при невыясненных обстоятельствах происходит ошибка. У меня эта ситуация не воспроизводится (и xml выглядит хорошо), а у пользователя появляется при каждом запуске и смене значения enum. Как просмотреть что за xml сформировался у пользователя я не знаю, придти к нему и поставить на его компьютер Fiddler я не могу.

Comment: я понял. значит используются встроенные средства. Посмотрите в версии дотнета/xml. Может у пользователя стоит старая/бажная версия

Comment: Настройте логирование пользователю, пусть приложение пишет свой каждый вздох в файл. Сделайте скрытую настройку для включения механизма. Но вообще такие проблемы начинают выяснять с версии операционной системы, дотнета, поддержки TLS, наличия кастомного антивируса и т.д. То есть с выяснения операционного окружения, потом рекомендовать пользователю обновить все что можно, в большинстве случаев проблемы такого рода решаются простым обслуживанием компа. Простите, но этот совет должен быть здесь: уже пора задуматься уходить от WCF на Web API, ну или сразу на модный gRPC.

Comment: думаю, автору вопроса не нужно пока переходить куда то. Но вот антивирус (если точнее - фаервол) может попортить жизнь.